# Angular ng-repeat not updating array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array as follows:

```
[7500, 15000, 21300, 3600]
```

This array is printed in the view using `ng-repeat`. But my problem is, I'm updating this array every second using `setInterval`, it is fired, and works on controller but updated value is not shown in view. My code is given below:

**JavaScript**

```
 angular
    .module('controllers')
    .controller('DashCtrl', DashCtrl);

 function DashCtrl($scope, $window) {

     var dash = this;
     dash.alarmList = JSON.parse() ; // [7500, 15000, 21300, 3600]

     dash.updateClock = function() {
        for(var key in dash.alarmList) {
            dash.alarmList[key] --;
        }
     }

     setInterval( dash.updateClock, 1000);
 }
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="list">

  <a class="item item-icon-left" ng-repeat="alarm in dash.alarmList">
    <i class="icon ion-person-stalker"></i>
    {{alarm}}
    <span class="badge badge-assertive">0</span>
  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: What is the intended update made to the alarmlist's values? Are you meaning to decrement 1 from the alarm every second, like a countdown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`$interval`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) instead of `setInterval` which will internally call `$scope.apply()` to update bindings.

```
 angular
    .module('controllers')
    .controller('DashCtrl', DashCtrl);

 function DashCtrl($scope, $window, $interval) {

     var dash = this;
     dash.alarmList = JSON.parse() ; // [7500, 15000, 21300, 3600]

     dash.updateClock = function() {
        for(var key in dash.alarmList) {
            dash.alarmList[key] --;
        }
     }

     $interval(dash.updateClock, 1000);
 }
```

Note: Intervals created by this service must be explicitly destroyed when you are finished with them.

Answer (score 1):

> Angular's wrapper for window.setInterval. The fn function is executed
>   every delay milliseconds.
>
> The return value of registering an interval function is a promise.
>   This promise will be notified upon each tick of the interval, and will
>   be resolved after count iterations, or run indefinitely if count is
>   not defined. The value of the notification will be the number of
>   iterations that have run. To cancel an interval, call
>   $interval.cancel(promise).
>
> In tests you can use $interval.flush(millis) to move forward by millis
>   milliseconds and trigger any functions scheduled to run in that time.
>
> Note: Intervals created by this service must be explicitly destroyed
>   when you are finished with them. In particular they are not
>   automatically destroyed when a controller's scope or a directive's
>   element are destroyed. You should take this into consideration and
>   make sure to always cancel the interval at the appropriate moment. See
>   the example below for more details on how and when to do this.

You have to use $interval

```
$interval(function(){dash.updateClock}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, Angular doesn’t get notified that the value has been changed and the digest cycle doesn’t run.  Some angular directives/services (`ng-click, $timeout, $interval, etc.`) automatically trigger the digest cycle.  So, either use $interval instead of setInterval or manually trigger the digest cycle by wrapping your for loop inside `$scope.$apply(() => { /* your code here */ });`

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be some logical flaws in your code. Try the following:

```
<script>function DashCtrl() {

     var dash = this;
     var alarmlist = {
        0: 7500,
        1: 1500,
        2: 21300,
        3: 3600
      };

      dash.alarmList = alarmlist;


     dash.updateClock = function() {
        for(var i in dash.alarmList) {
            dash.alarmList[i] -= 1;
        }
        console.log(dash.alarmList);
     }

     setInterval( dash.updateClock, 1000);
 }
 DashCtrl();
 </script>
```

I assume you need the $interval wrapper too in the case of angular.